# Почему не запускается Phonegap приложение на IOS?

Tags: phonegap, cordova

Приложение отлично работает на андроид, но на IOS не хочет работать, хотя все правильно настроил (в плане дев аккаунт и тд), предыдущее приложение точно так же настраивал  и все отлично работало.В чем может быть проблема?